# How to set a environment variable for a python script on windows10?

Tags: python, command-line, environment-variables, command, alias

Now I am running the python file everytime like this:

`python C:/my/path/to/python/file.py`

I want to replace it with one word command like this

`myfile`

The same command should work from **command_prompt, powershell and powershell_ise** and it should work from any directory that I am in.

Comment: Why don't you use a text editor like VSCode? You could even create your custom keyboard shortcut over there to run any program file. Like mine is `F5`, so just clicking `F5` runs the program on the terminal

Answer (score 1):

You can basically create `Custom Environment Variables`. This link will guide how can you do that.

Link: [Create Custom Environment Variables in Windows](https://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/create-custom-environment-variables-in-windows/)

> The file option is interesting because it means you can also create an environment variable to launch a program. For example, you can point an environment variable to any EXE file on your system. When you invoke the variable, it will launch the program. If you have a custom executable program file stored in some random directory on your PC, this is an easy way to launch it without having to go look for it.

Or if you want to run your python script from anywhere, technically not anywhere but from other directory also then you can create a `.bat` file. And opening that `.bat` will automatically run your python script. You can create a `.bat` by :

1. Right click create a new file. Name it as `script.bat`.
2. Right click on `script.bat` and open it in Notepad.
3. Copy/paste this script `python C:/my/path/to/python/file.py`
4. Save it and run that `script.bat`.
   It will automatically run you `file.py` from here. You can place `script.bat` in your preferred place like in `desktop`.

Comment: I didnt get, to open that bat file wouldn't I have to navigate to whereever that batfile is saved? will typing `script.bat` from any directory work?

Comment: No, that's why I am suggesting you to save `bat` file in desktop. And this is the alternative approach,  I strongly suggest first approach!

Comment: Why Desktop ? Desktop isn't my default command_prompt, or powershell directory.

Comment: In your PC isn't desktop starts at first? Or is there any other thing?

Comment: desktop isnt't the default powershell or command prompt . We dont use mouse. only commandline. We can run only commands, not click anything. default is `C:\Users\hp>`

Comment: Okay then in that default folder where powershell opens!

Comment: basically we need it to be avaiable from any directory. not just from default directory. from any project. will typing `script.bat` from any directory work?

Comment: Please read the answer carefully!!!!!!! By creating environment variable you can access file from anywhere!!

Comment: I thought you gave two different answers . I was talking about your second answer. will typing `script.bat` from any directory work in your second approach without doing anythng from your first approach?

Comment: Yeah! I had gave you 2 different answer, but now I am asking you to read first answer if you want to access file from anywhere :) if you want to do that then you again start problem from start from .py file?

Comment: After understanding my problem in detail now If you think that the 2nd approach is invalid I would suggest to remove it to clear confusion.

Comment: I suspect if you are taking with me without  testing what I had told you!

Comment: I am suggesting you last time, Try to follow first approach which I believe is easy and starlight forward. Just follow this step, go to `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\System` and there is `Advance System Setting` in right corner > `Environment Variable` > `New` > Add `Variable Name` lets say `runpy`  and value `python C:/my/path/to/python/file.py` and `Ok` `apply`.... Back. Now Open terminal and type `%runpy%` that should run your file in cmd. :)

Comment: Now I found that your question is clearly asking _How to set a environment variable for a python script on windows10?_ And this is the clear answer for that!

Answer (score 1):

If you made the python an exe and cd into the directory or add it to your environment variables you could call it by myfile or myfile.exe

Another way would be to make a batch file that contains

```
python C:/my/path/to/python/file.py
```

and name it myfile which would allow you to call the batch file and it would type out the rest

Also if you cd into C:/my/path/to/python
you could type python file.py instead of the whole path.